# Boost memory_order_consume Example

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, atomic

I was looking at a Boost example regarding atomic operations and the happens-before relationship, and I'm a bit confused.
In the "happens-before through release and consume" section, there is the following example that they say it is  erroneous, but I cannot see it :

```
atomic<int> a(0);
complex_data_structure data[2];
```

thread1:

```
      data[1] = ...; /* A */
      a.store(1, memory_order_release);
```

thread2:

```
      int index = a.load(memory_order_consume);
      complex_data_structure tmp;
      if (index == 0)
          tmp = data[0];
      else
          tmp = data[1];
```

[Boost Example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0_beta1/doc/html/atomic/thread_coordination.html#atomic.thread_coordination.release_consume)

Here is what I understood (please correct me if I am wrong):

1. If the `load` operation by *thread2* precedes the `store` operation by *thread1*, then  `tmp` will be `data[0]`.
2. If the `store` operation operation by *thread1* precedes the `load` operation by *thread2*, then `tmp` will be `data[ 1 ]` because the `store(1,memory_order_release)` by *thread1* will ensure that all prior writes to other memory locations are visible to *thread2* even though `data[]` is not computationally-dependent on index.

Can somebody please clarify the error they're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `release/consume`, writes to variables prior to the `store(release)`
are only guaranteed to be visible at the matching `load(consume)` *if, and only if,*
the variables are dependent on the variable used in the
`store(release)`-`load(consume)` pair.

By using `int` literals to index the `data[]` this dependency has been broken,
thus writes to `data[]` are not guaranteed to be visible after the
`a.load(consume)`.

Comment: Aha!  Okay.
I got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user2404835, no problem. I would recommend not accepting this answer for awhile and see if other more informative answers arrive. If not, then feel free to accept it then.